# Can I see the value of variables at any moment of Node JS app execution?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

Can I see the value of variables at any moment of Node JS app execution?
Like VSC debugger do ([screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60IOU.png)), but I can see values only when breakpoint hits and code stops.
I would like to see it in dynamic, imagine this like I trigger some button and can see what variables are in this moment of time.

Any information would be appreciated including what terms should I use for googling to figure it out.
(Of course, there is console.log, but I'm looking For some advanced functionality )

Comment: Loggin is the only way for you to see.

Comment: @Talg123 Sorry, you mean console.log command?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best method but it works:

```
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

function startListening() {
    rl.question("", (answer) => {
        eval(`console.log(${answer})`);
    

        startListening();
    });
}
startListening();
```

Add this to the file you want to "debug".

Now just type the variable name to the console you want to get.

Comment: Thank you. Looks curious, I'm trying to figure out how to reach values of variables I defined in code, now I'm getting "ReferenceError: firstTemp is not defined" error constantly

Comment: This works for global scope variables, is your variable inside a function?

Comment: Here is my code if you don't mind to look: https://codepen.io/Georgia1One/pen/KKMojxw?editors=0010. A lot of noise, but for example taking "defaulttimeout" variable - it is defined globally as I understand, and should be visible from a command from the console (imgur: https://imgur.com/a/0eCLW56)

Comment: I placed your block on 44th line, on level of  "var first" line (not visible in my codepen)